# Is there an adjective for "caused/causable by mutation"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Some context: I'm currently trying to write a pen&paper RPG rulebook. Characters can have abilities. Some of the abilities can only be "inherited" when creating the character, some can be learned, some can only be achieved via genetic mutation.

I'm trying to annotate the abilities with short, descriptive adjectives and the most useful I could find was "mutagenic", but that actually seems to mean "causing mutation". Is there a counterpart for "(possibly) caused by" mutation?

Since the rules ask for an example sentence, the annotations would be interpreted like this:
"Human characters cannot normally have Nightvision. It can only be acquired ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traits acquired via mutation would be called "mutational". https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mutational

Comment: Okay, should have been obvious...Anyway, thank you!